# Calculating quantile for inverse transformed Gamma

Tags: quantiles

I have an inverse transformed Gamma by the specific  domain but I have a difficulty of finding quantile for this distribution. The issue is my quantile is smaller than my minim data set.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by " inverse transformed Gamma"? Do you mean a Gamma distributed variable that you have taken the inverse of, or something else? Can you explain how you're finding the quantile? Which quantile is it? How large is the sample? Why is this quantile being smaller than the minimum value in the data a problem? What is it you specifically need assistance with here?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your contribution,
I am working on inverse transformed gamma distribution with a specific domain which is 13

Comment: What do you mean by specific domain ? Think about editing your question instead to make things easier for the readers.

Comment: I mean I mention random variable between 13 and INF not from zero to INF.